# Is there a package for supporting two types of comments?

Tags: comment

So, you would be able to setup it like this

```
(setq
  one-line-comment "//"
  multi-line-comment-start "/*"
  multi-line-comment-end "*/")
```

And use one command to comment anything. If nothing is selected it would comment one line otherwise it would use multi line comment. And most important if you inside a comment it would uncomment both types of comments. I know about `newcomment.el` but I cannot figure out if it's possible to configure it in such way, especially for uncommenting multi line comments.

Comment: I would suggest broadening your question, so that someone will write up a solution if it doesn't exist in a current package.  Consider specifying the major-mode that you intend to use this with.

Comment: It should work in any major mode. For example JavaScript has two types of comments

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a special package for this. Emacs offers such a feature out of the box.  And as @ais indicated in a comment, it is available to use for any mode.

See the Elisp manual, node [Syntax Class Table](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html):

```
Comment starters: ‘<’
Comment enders: ‘>’
 Characters used in various languages to delimit comments.  Human
 text has no comment characters.  In Lisp, the semicolon (‘;’)
 starts a comment and a newline or formfeed ends one.

Generic comment delimiters: ‘!’
 Characters that start or end a special kind of comment.  _Any_
 generic comment delimiter matches _any_ generic comment delimiter,
 but they cannot match a comment starter or comment ender; generic
 comment delimiters can only match each other.

 This syntax class is primarily meant for use with the
 ‘syntax-table’ text property (*note Syntax Properties::).  You can
 mark any range of characters as forming a comment, by giving the
 first and last characters of the range ‘syntax-table’ properties
 identifying them as generic comment delimiters.
```

and more particularly node [Syntax Flags](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Flags.html).

(See how it is done for C code, for example, by checking the Lisp sources.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I came up with to comment the way I like:

```
(defun comment-or-uncomment-line-or-region ()
  "Comments or uncomments the current line or region."
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (comment-or-uncomment-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (if (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (looking-at "[[:space:]]*$"))
        (comment-dwim nil)
      (comment-or-uncomment-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-;") 'comment-or-uncomment-line-or-region)
```

This should do everything the way you want, except that multi line comments are formatted as multiple single line comments. If want a package instead of a home-grown function, you can try the [`comment-dwim-2` package](https://github.com/remyferre/comment-dwim-2), but it seems like this does more or less the same thing my function does. Also, see the various answers and links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499206/emacs-mode-multiline-comments) which discusses multi line comments.